# Vue.js Routing error when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I load a page with prop id e.d. ***/blogpost/edit/1*** via routerlink.
First this page loads perfectly but when i refresh the page everything disapears, i get this error in the console:

***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -> main.js:1***

And the whole page is blank.

I already use history mode in the router, my router and routes looks like this:

**Router**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import routes from './routes';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: __dirname,
    routes
});

export default router;
```

**Routes**

```
{
    name: "blogpost/edit",
    path: '/blogpost/edit/:id',
    component: Blogpost,
},
```

Does any of you encoutered this problem and/or know how to fix this?

Comment: How are you serving the page? Might be your server is not handling the incoming request correctly because the URL isn’t the base URL

Comment: I am currently running this all locally hosted (localhost:8081/blogpost/edit/1).

Comment: But what is serving the pages? Apache? Nginx? Node/Express? Something else? Have you created the proper wildcard routes there to understand what to do with that URL?

Comment: I use the webpack server,   **"start": "webpack-dev-server --config build/webpack.config.js --open"**, i have not create wildcards of any kind.